# How to add CORS (cross origin policy) to all domains in NGINX?

Tags: magento, nginx, cors, jsonp, font-face

I have created a folder that will be used for serving static files (CSS, images, fonts and JS etc) I will eventually CNAME the folder into a subdomain for usage on a CDN to work with my Magento 2 setup.

I want to allow ALL domains ALL access via CORS - Cross Origin Policy and I want to cache the data too. This is what I have. (I am not asking for security suggestions or tips on JSONP issues - I want global access to the file directory please)

```
location /cdn-directory/ {

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM *";
        expires +1y;
    }

}
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) it says `X-Frame-Options` supports `ALLOW-FROM uri` but cannot see examples of using `*` (all domains) or adding certain multiple domains in this `ALLOW-FROM`. I need to allow all domains access to my static files folder.

Comment: Your configuration is correct and it adds the header to the requests as defined (I tested), I'm not sure what you are asking here: How to globally define response headers in nginx? The usage of X-Frame-Options? Keep in mind that Google Chrome and Safari do not support X-Frame-Options `ALLOW FROM`, there might not be much example because because of that

Comment: Have you tried using `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *`? I believe  CSP headers supersede X-Frame-Options so might make a good complement.

Comment: I want to know if I can have multiple domains use my content as it seems ALLOW-FROM uri is only restricted to one call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
location /cdn-directory/ {

location ~* \.(js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'public';
    add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    expires +1y;
  } 
}
```

http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Answer (score 6):

I didn't try it i nginx, but allowing the origin of current request works in tomcat:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM $http_origin";
```

Comment: This snippet, especially together with the rest of the config from the OP, will simply result in **CACHE POISON**.  Not to mention that the `Origin` header might be missing, and even if present, `ALLOW-FROM` is not supposed to include the address scheme (e.g., it's never supposed to start from stuff like `http://`).

Comment: I did not want the bounty awarded to you. How can I delete this?

Answer (score 4):

Allowing all the domains to embed the resources (e.g., within `iframe` et al) is the default, and thus requires no extra headers.

The sole purpose of the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP Response Header is to prevent the interactive resources from being embedded in an `iframe` by an external site, thus if your intention is an `ALLOW-FROM *` (which is indeed not supposed to be a valid directive, as per above), then you should just omit this whole header altogether, and anyone would be able to have full and proper access to your static resources from any domain just as you please.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you actually want CORS (Cross Origin Request Sharing) rather than just embedding in an iframe the configuration would be:

```
location /cdn-directory/ {

    location ~* \.(js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        expires +1y;
    }

}
```

Comment: +repped for your suggestion thanks this looks appealing enough to try.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but I have used the following headers on a Magento 1.8.x install for CORS:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
```